# Migrating Kubernetes cluster to other OpenStack region

Tags: kubernetes, openstack, etcd, openstack-cinder

I am trying to migrate Kubernetes cluster (master and worker instances) to different OpenStack region. I managed to start cluster after some simple modifications (changed cloud-config, node labels). There is one problem left - storage. In this setup I use OpenStack Internal Cloud Provider which manages cinder volumes as PV for pods. New region uses different zone name and volume types. Also volume ids have changed. It is not possible to change this values by modifying SC and PV  definitions via e.g. kubectl.

I wonder if it is possible to change this directly in etcd database?
So far, I tried to modify PV definition, but it appears that Kubernetes inserts also additional characters and modifying it is not so obvious.

What I did:

1. Get PV definition from etcd and saved to file:
   `docker run --rm -it --net host -v /etc/kubernetes:/etc/kubernetes k8s.gcr.io/etcd:3.4.3-0 etcdctl --cert /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.crt --key /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.key --cacert /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --endpoints https://kube-dev02-master01:2379 get /registry/persistentvolumes/pvc-1625baa0-e36c-4e2b-ad3d-0dfecc910ae0 --print-value-only > pv1.txt`.
2. I changed region name, zone name and volume id (with vi).
3. Loaded modified value to etcd:
   `docker run --rm -it --net host -v /etc/kubernetes:/etc/kubernetes k8s.gcr.io/etcd:3.4.3-0 etcdctl --cert /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.crt --key /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.key --cacert /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --endpoints https://kube-dev02-master01:2379 put /registry/persistentvolumes/pvc-1625baa0-e36c-4e2b-ad3d-0dfecc910ae0 "$(cat pv1.txt)"`
4. Checked PV from kubectl:

```
[kubeadmin@kube-dev02-master01 ~]$ kubectl get pv
Error from server: illegal base64 data at input byte 5
```

So it seems that something could be wrong with encoding, but I do not know where.

[Output of PV value stored in etcd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iXYq.png)

Kubernetes v1.17.5, etcd v.3.4.3-0 installed with Kubeadm.